# Hiding the Stop editing link when the QuickEdit grid is closed in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, custom

I am trying to replicate the "Stop editing this list" link that is at the top of the page when in QuickEdit Mode. My link will be at the bottom. I want to the hide the when not in QuickEdit Mode. The code is returning nothing regardless of the mode it is in and there is a Console Error saying GetCtxFromView is undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gridinfo = GetCtxFromView(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
        if (gridinfo.inGridMode) {
        //in grid mode 
        document.getElementById("lynk").style.display='block';
        }else{
        //in normal mode
        document.getElementById("lynk").style.display='hidden';
        }
</script>
    
    
<a href="#" id="lynk" onclick="ExitGrid(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);">Stop</a> editing this list.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a console error saying `GetCtxFromView` is `undefined` is because you are trying to call that function before it is loaded and available.

Any Javascript you load on to a page using an inline `<script>` block will be executed *immediately* as it's loaded.  Meanwhile, all the default/built-in SharePoint Javascript functions you are trying to take advantage of (`GetCtxFromView` and `ExitGrid`) are being loaded behind the scenes as SharePoint loads all of its many Javascript files where all of those functions are defined (`init.js`, `sp.init.js`, `sp.core.js`, `sp.runtime.js`, `sp.js`, etc., etc.). The loading process for all those scripts is complicated and takes a bit of time. So it's very likely that your script gets executed well before `GetCtxFromView` is actually available to be called.

One thing you can try to do is use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` (which is available very early in the page load process) to tell SharePoint you have a function you want to be executed once the page body is loaded (kind of similar to jQuery's `$(document).ready()`).  This will delay the execution of your function, hopefully long enough that `GetCtxFromView` is available when you want it.

To do that, you need to put your code inside a named function, and then `push()` the function name *as a string* on to the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` collection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHideButtonByMode() {
        var gridinfo = GetCtxFromView(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
        if (gridinfo.inGridMode) {
            //in grid mode 
            document.getElementById("lynk").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            //in normal mode
            document.getElementById("lynk").style.display = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('showHideButtonByMode');
</script>
```

Now, as I said, the way SharePoint loads its background scripts is complicated and takes a little while, so that may not even be enough of a delay.  If it's not, you could try something a bit more extreme, which is to tell SharePoint not to execute your function until *a specific SharePoint Javascript file has been loaded*.  You can do that by using the built in `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` function (which is also available very early in the page load process).  To do that, you would replace the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push()` line in the above example with:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { 
    showHideButtonByMode();
}, 'sp.js');
```

This is essentially telling SharePoint "wait until the file `sp.js` is loaded, and then execute this anonymous function", and then inside the anonymous function you are calling your named function.  You could also do it like

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(showHideButtonByMode, 'sp.js');
```

but to me it makes it a bit easier to see/understand what is going on with the anonymous function, plus, if you have to add other steps, you can do it inside the anonymous function.  I guess you could also do it by putting all of your code inside the anonymous function, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        var gridinfo = GetCtxFromView(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
        if (gridinfo.inGridMode) {
            //in grid mode 
            document.getElementById("lynk").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            //in normal mode
            document.getElementById("lynk").style.display = 'hidden';
        }
    }, 'sp.js');
</script>
```

Now, last point - these last variations on the example using `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` are all using `sp.js` as the script file to wait for.  That's making the assumption that `GetCtxFromView` is defined in `sp.js` or one of its dependencies that gets loaded earlier.

I don't know for sure that that function is defined in that file, so even that might not work.  If it doesn't, what you would need to do is do the research to find out *what SP Javascript file has `GetCtxFromView`*, and then change where you refer to `sp.js` to refer to that other Javascript file, to make sure that you are waiting for the file to load that holds the function definition for the function you are tying to use.